# Showing all Custom Options on Transactional Emails

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, transactional-mail

I want to show all **custom options** (even not selected ones) on order emails. And I want to strikeout unselected ones. I think I need to work on `/app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml` but I couldn't do it. `(My Magento version is 1.9.2.1)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You want to show all product option in your order email then you need to customize code in this file :

> /app/design/frontend/XXX/YYY/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Just replace `getItemOptions` code block with this code:

```
<? if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                <?php
                if($option['label'] == "THETITLEOFTHEVALUEIWANTEDTOMARK"){
                    $exploded_ids = explode(",", $option['option_value']);
                    $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_item->getProductId());
                    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $value) {
                        if($value->getType() == "checkbox" && $value->getTitle() == "THETITLEOFTHEVALUEIWANTEDTOMARK"){
                            $values = $value->getValues();
                            foreach ($values as $values) {
                                $option_item =  $values->getData();
                                if(in_array($option_item["option_type_id"],$exploded_ids)){
                                    echo $option_item["title"] . ", ";
                                }else{
                                    echo "<strike>".$option_item["title"] . "</strike>, ";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    echo nl2br($option['value']);
                }
                ?>
```

Hope It will help You.

Comment: Ok, but how?

'        <?php if ($this->getItemOptions()): ?>
        <dl style="margin:0; padding:0;">
            <?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
            <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
            <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
                <?php echo nl2br($option['value']) ?>
            </dd>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>'

I need to modify these lines but I don't know what should I replace with.

Comment: See here http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-get-custom-option-value-from-order/

Comment: It just gets order's selected options too. It's no different than original code. But I fixed my problem like this; http://paste.ofcode.org/A6jiV2mP5dqFev7aDervsi

Comment: ok great i posting your code in my answer, You may accept this answer to help other people

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to repost, but this answer on stackoverflow might help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036507/list-item-options-in-magento-email-template/44887149#44887149